# What the construction "have something done" implies

Tags: passive-voice, past-participles

If the construction is used in past tense as follows:

I had my computer fixed.

Is it possible it implies that the repair job is done and the computer is ok now? 
That is my computer has been fixed.

Or, 
Is it just I let somebody do it.

Comment: Are you asking about the tense of the verb *to have* or the meaning of the verb *to fix*?

Comment: More interestingly, I don't think "I had my computer fixed" involves passive voice.

Comment: I'm not wondering about the tense of the verb. It's written in past tense, though. I'm asking if the construction "I had my computer fixed" could imply "My computer has been fixed, and now it's working." What I want to know exactly is whether it could imply the "fixing activity" is completed.  I know it's not passive voice.

Comment: It's past tense, not present perfect.  So the way I read it is that at some time in the past you had the computer fixed and at that time it was working but it may not be now.  "I had my computer fixed but it's broken down again" seems perfectly fine to me.  "I've had my computer fixed." would imply to me that it was still working.

Answer (score 1):

"I had my computer fixed" means that your computer went from the state of being broken, to being fixed, and that someone else carried out the fix on your instruction.

Without any other information, there is a strong implication that your computer is currently working. But it is possible that your computer was broken, got fixed, but has since broken again.

Answer (score 0):

"I had my computer fixed" does imply that:

- your computer has been fixed
- someone else did it